# Parsing json that doesn't seem to be properly formatted

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to do some work with real estate data and after failing on my own managed to borrow a code that pulled *some* of the data. Unfortunately I have no idea how to parse the rest, as the json formatting is very confusing to me. This is not my area of expertise so if anyone has ideas on how to approach this I would greatly appreciate it. If needed I can post the entire json but it's very long.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
import pprint

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
HEADERS = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome 61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1'
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def get_soup(address):
        page_request = requests.get(address, headers=HEADERS)
        return BeautifulSoup(page_request.text, "lxml")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def fetch_content(soup, verbose=False):
    item = soup.select_one("script#hdpApolloPreloadedData").text
    d = json.loads(item)['apiCache']
    return json.loads(d)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def process_fetched_content(raw_dictionary=None):
    if raw_dictionary is not None:
        keys = [k for k in raw_dictionary.keys() if k.startswith('VariantQuery{"zpid":')]
        property_info = dict((k.split(':')[-1].replace('}',''), raw_dictionary.get(k).get('property', None)) for k in keys)
        return property_info
    else:
        return None

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
if __name__ == "__main__":

    link = 'https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2408-Comstock-Ct-Naperville-IL-60564/5367006_zpid/'
    soup = get_soup(link)
    results = process_fetched_content(raw_dictionary = fetch_content(soup, verbose=False))
    pprint.pprint(results)
```

Sidenote: I know zillow doesn't take kindly to scraping but I'm not trying to pull data at a large scale so not too concerned.

Comment: Is it the `item` variable that contains `json` in the `fetch_content()` function? You seem to be decoding just fine with `d = json.loads(...`, except you don't want to repeat that. Did you mean `return d`?

Comment: From what I gather all the data I need comes from within 'apiCache', if that makes sense. My problem is I can't figure out how to pull the information that comes after the info in 'property'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can (Unless I Understood the question horribly wrong)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd
import pprint

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome 61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def get_soup(address):
    page_request = requests.get(address, headers=HEADERS)
    return BeautifulSoup(page_request.text, "lxml")


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def fetch_content(soup, verbose=False):
    item = soup.select_one("script#hdpApolloPreloadedData").text
    d = json.loads(item)["apiCache"]
    return json.loads(d)


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
def process_fetched_content(raw_dictionary=None):
    if raw_dictionary is not None:
        keys = [
            k for k in raw_dictionary.keys() if k.startswith('VariantQuery{"zpid":')
        ]
        property_info = dict(
            (
                k.split(":")[-1].replace("}", ""),
                raw_dictionary.get(k).get("property", None),
            )
            for k in keys
        )
        return raw_dictionary, property_info
    else:
        return None


# -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
if __name__ == "__main__":

    link = "https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2408-Comstock-Ct-Naperville-IL-60564/5367006_zpid/"
    soup = get_soup(link)
    raw, results = process_fetched_content(raw_dictionary=fetch_content(soup, verbose=False))
    
    # Traverse through results
    for value in results.values():
        for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
            print(f'{inner_key}: {inner_value}')

    # Traverse through raw dictionary
    
    for key, value in raw.items():
        print(f'{key}:')
        for inner_key, inner_value in value.items():
            print(f'\t{inner_key}:')
            try:
                for inner_2_key, inner_2_value in inner_value.items():
                    print(f'\t\t{inner_2_key}:')
                    try:
                        for inner_3_key, inner_3_value in inner_2_value.items():
                            print(f'\t\t\t{inner_3_key}:')
                            try:
                                for inner_4_value in inner_3_value:
                                    for inner_4_1_key, inner_4_1_value in inner_4_value.items():
                                        print(f'\t\t\t\t{inner_4_1_key}: {inner_4_1_value}')
                            except:
                                for inner_4_key, inner_4_value in inner_3_value.items():
                                    print(f'\t\t\t\t{inner_4_key}: {inner_4_value}')        
                    except:
                        print(f'\t\t\t{inner_2_value}')
            except:
                print(f'\t\t{inner_value}')
```

Try this. Output is waay too long though. But it seems readable now...

Comment: That's pretty much what the original code does. What I'm looking for is the info that comes after. If you pprint raw_dictionary you can see.

Comment: So you want the entire thing `raw_dictionary` or the info that comes after `results` (To put it simply something like (`raw_dictionary` - `results`))?

Comment: If you look through raw_dictionary you can see the first key within 'property' seems to be 'NFSHDPBottomSlot' - I can't even get that to print out.

Comment: @Nick Try this now. I edited the answer.

Comment: i got this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/N/_py/zilprop.py", line 51, in <module>
    raw, results = process_fetched_content(raw_dictionary=fetch_content(soup, verbose=False))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Comment: Yeah my bad, I changed the above function to return raw dict and prop info. Should work now

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot closer than I could've gotten. There are still some lines that print out as dicts though, would that mean I need to continue with the try/except?

Comment: Yes exactly! you will just have to dig more deep into it. And that should do the trick!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you encounter any errors